# Best way to declare content element uids to use them in fluid templates

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I want to display some contentlement on every page with fluid templates. My solution was to create a typoscript element like:

```
lib.my.myelement= CONTENT
lib.my.myelement {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList = 15
    where = uid=99
  }
}
```

and then use it in the fluid template with:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.my.myelement" />
```

Another way is to create them directly in fluid with v:content.render or v:content.get. In this example I get all content elements on one page and save them in an array:

```
<v:variable.set name="contentElements" value="{v:content.get(column:'0', limit:'3', pageUid:'9',  render:'FALSE')}" />
```

---

I can not use the first solution, cause on this page there will be much different languages ( I could use it, but every time a new language is added I would have work to declare all new uids of the new elements in typoscript).

The second solution would work better, cause when you translate a page the element uids change, but the pageUid does not change. But here I have the problem that I don't just need all elements, I also have to identify each element.

Here is how I use the second solution:

```
<v:variable.set name="contentElements" value="{v:content.get(column:'0', limit:'3', pageUid:'9',  render:'FALSE')}" />

  <f:for each="{contentElements}" as="contentElement" iteration="footerIteration">
    <div class="column{v:math.sum(a: footerIteration.index, b: 1)}">
        <v:content.render contentUids="{0:contentElement.uid}" />
    </div>
  </f:for>
```

As you can see, I use every element the same way.

---

lets create a simple case:

I have a page with the pageUid = 10 (this page will have translations). On every of this translations will be 3 elements. Lets say 1 element got the "id" (with id I mean something how I can identify this element) `title1` and the other two elements have the id `list1` and `list2`.

And my question now is How could I access for example list1?

I hope its understandable, if something is not clear please leave a comment.

---

**Edit:** I could use the same order on every translation for the elements and then check the iteration in the for-loop (see the second solution) to identify them. But I wonder if there a better, cleaner way.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly... why doesn't it work to just use `where = colPos = 0` instead of `where = uid = 99` in the TypoScript snipped?

Comment: @Jost cause with colPos I would get all elements in this column. And in that first example I just want to select 1 element. And on what I want to create now there will be more then 1 element on that page (and in this column)

Comment: @Jost but you make me an idea. I could create a layout with more columns and then identify them via column. That could work

Comment: That would probably also more user friendly, because you can use a column label to make clear what happens with the content elements.

Comment: @Jost Yes I do it now this way and as you say its much more user friendly I can use a nice grid with rowspans and colspans to really show where the elements will be located. works great. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @Jost I have one more step to go. I use a page template now with a flux:grid and also do some styling in the page template. Now I search something similar to `v:content.render`or `v:content.get`but for a hole page. What I want to archive is to render the page with the page content and all its elements, but without the layout. Do you know any fluid-way or do I have to fall back to typoscript for this?

Comment: `EXT:fluidpages` defines page type 235 that does exactly that. Just append the parameter `type=235` to the request URI. If fluidpages wouldn't do that, you could create your own page type and set `config.disableAllHeaderCode = 1` for it.

Comment: @Jost with type 235 I get the page including the layout. I am not sure yet if it is possible to render this page in another page without the layout.

Comment: I use an empty layout not for this page. With type 235 I can call this page and have just the content I want. But how can I render that now?

Comment: @Jost I use a partial now to render the page whereever I want. I have the styling in the partial and in that partial i use v:content.render and select the different columns

Comment: Why is having multiple languages a problem? You can modify your Typoscript object to give you the correct language by adding select.languageField = sys_language_uid